# How normal is it for a job to be 'learn from google'?

Tags: software-industry, learning

I think employers are aware that a computer science graduate isn't coming out of the job knowing whatever framework they're using inside out, and are prepared to have the employee learn on the job.

However, it seems like a lot of jobs, that the expectation of the employee is that they'll learn from googling everything.

This image macro expresses this idea:

[image]

or this one:

[image]

I find this frustrating, because I'm not learning nearly as quickly as I was at university.

My question is - how common is this attitude by employers, and how else do employers upskill their employees?

Comment: Voting to close because we are not a research survice. Do your own surveys.

Comment: You must have had really good professors if you didn't rely on Google often.

Comment: @SomeCallMeSam It's not that I didn't use Google at university, it's more that the professors provided me with structured learning and told me what I need to know.

Comment: @dwjohnston there's definitely less structured learning in the workplace. You did pay to go to school and the purpose was to teach you so it's probably an unreasonable expectation for the learning/teaching to be as high quality in the workplace. I think you're question may be slightly misinterpreted as you focus on "google" in particular and it sounds like you're wondering more about the learning environment in the office in general.

Answer (score 8):

Have you talked with your boss?  Different people have different learning styles and different sets of knowledge.  Some people prefer to learn by working through things with Google, StackOverflow, etc.  Others would rather pick up some books.  Others would rather go to a training class, a conference, or something else.  Don't assume that your boss knows how you best learn.

Generally, coming to your boss with a solution works better than coming to him with a problem.  For example, it's generally a lot more productive to bring a well thought out plan

> Hey boss, as you know, I'm trying to get up to speed with X and Y for
>   the Smith project.  I can work through it on my own but it would be a
>   lot more efficient for me if I could go to a training class on X so
>   that I understand the theory a better and so that I can make sure that
>   I'm doing things the right way.  There is a 5-day class in X coming up
>   at the training center down the road that costs $$.  Is that something
>   that we might be able to get into the training budget?  If not, there
>   is also a local conference in X coming up at the local community
>   college that's a lot less expensive.  I'd need to get a couple days
>   off to attend.

than to just dump a problem in his lap.  Of course, this requires that you do the leg work of identifying what you need, identifying options that would work for you and the company.  The more expensive your preferred option, the more likely you'd want to have acceptable alternatives available.

When you're thinking about options, don't forget about internal options as well.  If there are a number of people learning X at the same time, perhaps you can organize some "lunch and learn" sessions where everyone takes a turn digging in to one aspect or another and presenting their research to the team.  Or perhaps there is someone in the company that is an expert in X and you just need your manager to get some of that expert's time to do some teaching.